# ios 8 Homescreen webapp, turning iPad off and on stops javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, web-applications, ios8

I have a fullscreen HTML5 web app for iPads and have just installed IOS 8 to try it out and it all works perfectly until you power the iPad off and back on. As soon as the web app relaunches javascript just stops and loading new pages doesn't restart it.

When opening the same page in Safari on the iPad, turning the iPad off and on it carries on working as expected.

Anyone else noticed this or come up with a work around?

Comment: Solutions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008300/how-to-resume-javascript-timer-on-ios8-web-app-after-screen-unlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to me resolved in the iOS8.1.1 update.

Comment: I discovered the same thing myself this morning. Only took them two months to fix it!!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this this problem too. At the moment there seems to be no work around. 
According to Sencha this is a problem natively.

> "This bug is easily reproduced by simply calling setTimeout(callback,
>   1) or requestAnimationFrame(callback) via some button or event. When
>   you first open your application, you’ll notice all timing functions
>   are working fine. However if you lock your phone and then unlock to
>   return to your application, you’ll see none of the timing functions
>   can call callbacks anymore. They are simply broken at a native level.
>   There is no reset, no bringing your application back to life, it’s a
>   kill it and restart situation."
>   http://www.sencha.com/blog/apple-shows-love-for-html5-with-ios-8

Your best bet is to report this bug to Apple and hopefully they’ll patch this in the next update (which should be coming around late September).

Comment: Glad I'm not going mad. I submitted it to them at the time but still haven't heard anything back.

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded and tested the beta version of ios8.1 and it's still broken, I think we need as many people as possible to report the bug Apple to get it noticed.