# How to resume JavaScript timer on iOS8 web app after screen unlock?

Tags: javascript, html, ios8

On iOS8 this HTML5 web app does not resume the js timer after the screen is locked and then unlocked if the webapp was active AND launched from the homescreen icon.  On iOS7 the timer would continue in this situation.  I need the timer to continue after the screen is unlocked - any tips to achieve this?

Note/ Please add the web app to the homescreen first using Safari's "add to home screen" via the sharing button.  Running the page inside Safari does not cause the issue described above.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        var tim;
        function go() {
            tim = window.setInterval(action, 1000);
        }
        function action() {
            document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = new Date().getTime().toString();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="go()">
    <div id="x"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems all setTimeout and setInterval fail after screen unlock

Comment: comparing a web worker timer to local timer detects if local timer stops.  we can then document.write('please restart') as issuing window.location.reload() does not fix timer issues

Comment: also websocket connections are completely broken after this.

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem, but it seems to be more far reaching. For example I have a web app that is typically saved to the home screen. Since installing iOS 8 on some test devices, if the device is locked and then unlocked again, despite my web app still being open and full screen, all subsequent AJAX requests receive no response.

By inspecting Apache's web logs I can see the back end server receives the request and sends a valid response, but neither the success, fail nor complete events execute.

Comment: I would take a look at iOS's (Safari's) documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html), and take a specific look at the "unload" event. When you exit Safari, this event is fired. Perhaps you can listen to that and stop the timer (save it in localStorage or something) then resume?

Comment: @SkyWookiee i just tested this and unfortunately pagehide and unload events do not fire when the screen is locked

Comment: these issues are not resolved with iOS 8.0.2

Comment: **Once again, Apple makes things difficult!** You could monitor for a tap anywhere onscreen or any event that could possibly fire from user interaction which would check if the timers are running. If they are not, then restart the timers, AJAX connections, WebSockets, etc.

Comment: iOS 8.1 beta 1 shows this is not resolved

Comment: This obviously changes the look and feel, but removing the 
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 
allows the app to work normally.

Comment: I worked around this using phone gap a 10 line html loader that just redirects to the real webapp. Of course it is a bit slower but it works, and I can suggest users download it from my webpage, and if installed a custom url allows it to be launched, so seamless enough to run with - let me know if anybody wants more details

Comment: 8.1.1 fixes this! huzzah!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution we ended up does not address all the broken functionality after sleep mode in IOS8, but rather just ajax requests/setTimeout/setInterval/requestAnimationFrame and their respective clear functions.

#### Other things broken after sleep mode:

- -webkit-transition opacity causes non-selectable areas
- worker.postMessage called while keyboard opening permanently kills all WebWorkers
- window bouncing/panning can kill all WebWorkers.
- overflowchange/resize events no longer work.  You need to rework any logic that depends on them`.

### To make a semi-working solution:

1. Override setTimeout/setInterval/requestAnimationFrame/clearInterval/clearTimeout/cancelAnimationFrame.  All of these functions need to postMessage to a webworker, where the webworker will perform setTimeout/setInterval accordingly.  You may need to set up a pausing mechinism for these functions as well, but I'm not 100% its necessary.
2. Override XMLHttpRequest so that when send is called, the request is actually performed on a webworker.
3. Create a pausing mechanism for all webworkers so that the main thread can determine when all webworkers have flushed their messages (Basically need to prevent postMessage from getting called on any worker while the keyboard is up).
4. Prevent keyboard popping up on editable elements.  After detecting a tap/click event on an editable element, you need to manually call the focus function.
5. Override focus function on editable elements that open the keyboard.  Focus will now call the pause workers function.  After all workers are paused, call the browser implementation of focus.
6. Add focusout event listener to editable elements so that resume workers function is called.

I have a semi-abstracted version on my github available for others.  We are using the github version in our fairly complex/large and heavily animation+ajax dependent application with very few issues.

https://github.com/TaDaa/IOS8-FIX

Answer (score 4):

Installing iOS 8.1.1 fixes this problem

Comment: This appears to be still a problem on iOS 8.1.2 :(

Comment: Confirmed. 8.1.2 Still killing setInterval.

Comment: The answer to an apple problem is never solved with another apple.

Comment: I can still see this issue on iOS 8.3 !! Can anyone else confirm?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of my working workaround.

Worker Script backgrond.js

```
setInterval(function () {
    postMessage(JSON.stringify({
        message: "tiktok",
        result: new Date().getTime()
    }));
}, 500);
```

Page Script - edited following comments 2014-10-30

```
var GUI = {
    iOS8: false,
    web_worker: null,
    tik: new Date().getTime(),
    tok: new Date().getTime(),
    init: function(){
        GUI.web_worker = new Worker("scripts/background.js");
        GUI.web_worker.onmessage = function (event) {
            var d = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (d.message === 'tiktok') {
                GUI.tik = d.result;
                if (Math.abs(GUI.tik - GUI.tok) > (15 * 1000) && GUI.iOS8 ) {
                    GUI.web_worker.terminate();
                    document.write('Please restart app after locking the screen.  Apple are working to prevent this issue.');
                 }
            };
        }
        setInterval(function () { GUI.tok = new Date().getTime(); }, 1000);
        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        GUI.iOS8 = ua.indexOf("os 8_0") !==-1 || ua.indexOf("os 8_1") !==-1;
  }
}

GUI.init();
```

Comment: additional note that userAgent check won't work now on iOS8.1, so anyone using this should really find a better way to detect ios8+ (e.g. I'm using uaParserJS)

Comment: Am I blind or you really create repeating timer on each message?

Comment: This will not work on iOS 8.1 (presumably on iOS 8 either) because postMessage is blocked while user pans screen. So this script (even when fixed) will false alarm.

Comment: @Andy you are correct about the scroll issue so we increased the difference check from 1.5s to 15s on our production system ps/ setInterval is called once after the webworker listener is configured

Comment: @ajayel you have setInterval inside of `onmessage` in your code, which seems like a misplaced curly bracket to me. Btw, based on your solution I made mine which takes into account touchmove: https://gist.github.com/pronebird/e8b87fb81dde9b0127ac. But I still think that this solution is unreliable because setInterval or postMessage can be delayed for whatever reason, device lag or power efficiency optimization..

Comment: Another issue I've noticed with this fix. It works (for me, with a few tweaks), when pressing the lock button. but when the device falls asleep on it's own, this no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

For another workaround for Ajax requests (involves serverside work) but does work here: [iOS 8 Bug - OnUpdateReady never called again when device returns from sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022261/ios-8-bug-onupdateready-never-called-again-when-device-returns-from-sleep/26182508#26182508)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the fix, and it does not work on my iphone4s and IOS8.

I found on my version phone an Alert Box crashes the app after you lock and come out of it...  Basically I put an alert box up That says PLease close and restart app when the settimeout timer stops updating by using a screen onlclick... SOoo Messy... THis is a terrible bug!

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed on iOS 8.1.3.

I'm using EaselJS library that uses requestAnimationFrame or setTimeout internally for updating tick. It had same problem on iOS 8.0.x, but it have been fixed on iOS 8.1.3.

Answer (score -1):

Presuming that every time the phone is unlocked, the `window.onload` event is handled, try this:

```
window.onload = function() { window.location.reload() }
```

As I don't currently have a device to test this on, this is only a blind guess. Hope this works for you.

Comment: unfortuneately onload doesn't fire on screen unlock

Comment: also note that even if you were to use ajayel's solution from above, and try to `window.location.reload()` instead of showing a message, the timers are STILL broken after reload.