# iOS 8 Bug - OnUpdateReady never called again when device returns from sleep

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, sleep

When an iOS 8 device running a Web Application (i.e. launched from a shortcut on the Home Screen) returns from it's Sleep state all asynchronous web requests made fail to trigger the OnUpdateReady callback.

The problem is quite easy to reproduce - simply put the two code files below on any web server and give it a try.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  If so is there any workarounds?

I'm posting this to try to attract attention to this bug in iOS 8 that has essentially ruined all of my web applications - we've had to recommend to NOT upgrade beyond iOS 7.  And yes, I've posted the problem on Apple Bug Reporter but I think no one is looking at these since it has been a long time.

app.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2014-09-24 - Test

CACHE:
default.html
```

default.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="app.manifest">
<head>
  <title>Test Harness</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var Test = new function () {
      var _GetEnd = function (oResult) {
        var sResult = ': ' +
          ((oResult.Value === true)
            ? 'Success'
            : 'Failure<br>' + oResult.Reason) +
          '<br>';

        var oLog = document.getElementById('idLog');
        oLog.innerHTML = (new Date()) + sResult + oLog.innerHTML

        setTimeout(_GetBegin, 1000);
      };

      var _GetBegin = function () {
        var sURL = 'app.manifest';
        var hAsyncCallback = _GetEnd;

        try {
          var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          oRequest.onreadystatechange =
            function () {
              if (oRequest.readyState != 4) return;
              if (oRequest.status != 200) {
                hAsyncCallback({ Value: false, Reason: oRequest.responseText });
              } else {
                hAsyncCallback({ Value: true, Reason: null });
              }
            };
          oRequest.open('GET', sURL, true);
          oRequest.send(null);
        } catch (e) {
          alert('Critical Error: ' + e.message );
        }
      };

      this.Start = function () { _GetBegin(); }
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="Test.Start();">
  <ol>
    <li>Put both app.manifest and default.html on a web server.</li>
    <li>Make sure this page is being launched from the Home screen as a web application.</li>
    <li>Press the sleep button while it is running.</li>
    <li>Press the wake button and unlock the phone to get back to this screen.</li>
    <li>Under iOS7x the page continues, under iOS8 the onreadystatechange never gets called again.</li>
  </ol>
  <div id="idLog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to let anyone that is interested know - Apple Closed my bug report with the following comment; "Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of another issue (#18042389) and will be closed."  However, Apple's bug reporting system does not permit me to view the other issue so I have no idea if it is really the same or if they are just blowing off this problem.  Also, as of iOS 8.0.2 the problem still persists.

Comment: Apple did the same to my bug, no idea what the status of 18042389 is. will repost the same bug until they ban me, then tweet about being banned - can't think of any other way at present

Comment: Another iOS8 Update (8.1) and still no joy - the problem continues.  I've reported the bug again this time specific to iOS 8.1 and included a link to this article.  Hopefully Apple will take notice soon.

Comment: No beta's to try yet either - I too have reported this bug as IOS 8.1 bug - but again apple closed it as a duplicate without giving any information. I have built a phone gap App as a short term fix,  having rolled out 300 iPod Touch users. 

BUT I have now got a Samsung S4 mini in front of me with the aim of rolling out the next 3,000 users on it rather than Apple. So far the feedback from our customers staff is that the Samsung makes them feel just as valued as the Apple iPod Touch.

Answer (score 1):

Installing iOS 8.1.1 fixes this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: As author told us, he has posted his question to attract attention on this iOS bug. And my post in short words provides information that Apple fixed this bug in new iOS release. I had the same problems and was very happy to know that this bug has gone in 8.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing the same issue, though my example is much simpler. Simply have a webclip application with

`<script>
    window.setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Johnny Five Alive! : " + new Date());
    },1000);
</script>`

on the page. Inspecting the console, after the sleep wakes up, no more console output. This works fine on iOS7 (my actual application is a complicated angularJS thing, I just boiled down the issue to this). Have you had any response on your bug report?

Comment: No response yet on Apple's Bug Reporter - it was my first time reporting a bug so I suspect it just went to the bottom of the list - that's why I posted to stack overflow hoping to raise awareness and get Apple's attention.

Answer (score 0):

Our workaround (for AJAX) is:

- Detect iOS8 (indeed 8.0.2 still has this) (also see this for other workaround: [How to resume JavaScript timer on iOS8 web app after screen unlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008300/how-to-resume-javascript-timer-on-ios8-web-app-after-screen-unlock))
- Remove the normal eventListeners, but keep the onProgress one

```js
...

this.onProgress = function(e)
{
    var position = e.position || e.loaded;
    var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
    var percentage = 0.0;
    if(total != 0)
    {
        percentage = position / total;
    }
    if(percentage == 1) {
        if( this.isIOS8() ) {
            recovery_uuid.get(uuid, _.bind(this.ios8ScriptReturn, this));
        }
    }
}

    ...

   //this gets called when the script with this UUID is injected
   this.ios8ScriptReturn = function(uuid, value) {
//then we create a simpler non real one 
        this.xhr = {};
        this.xhr.readyState = 4;
        this.xhr.status = 200;
        this.xhr.responseText = value;
        this.xhr.onreadystatechange = null;
        this.xhr.isFake = true; 

        //fake stateChnage
        this.onReadyStateChange();

    }
```

- add a UUID to each request

```js
if( this.isIOS8() ) {
    ajaxInfo.url += '&recoveryUUID='+ajaxInfo.uuid;
}
```

- Then still perform the XHR Send (that actually works fine, server gets and send back fine).
- server Side save the 'result' in database/file with the UUID as index/part of filename

```php
//detect the need for saving the result, and save it till requested
if(isset($_GET['recoveryUUID'])) {
    $uuid = $_GET['recoveryUUID'];
    RecoveryUUID::post($uuid, $result_json_string);
}
```

- On the client create a little helper global object that listens to the code injects and redirects them to the onProgress handler.

```js
   var RecoveryUUID = (function (_root) {
    function RecoveryUUID() {
        this.callbacks = {};
    }
    var proto = RecoveryUUID.prototype;
    proto.onLoaded = null;
    proto.set = function(uuid, value) {
        console.log('RECOVERY UUID: Received DATA: '+uuid+' value: '+value);
        if(typeof this.callbacks[uuid] != 'undefined') {
            this.callbacks[uuid](uuid, value);
            delete this.callbacks[uuid]; //auto remove
        } 
        if(this.onLoaded != null) {
            this.onLoaded(uuid, value);
        }

        var script = document.getElementById("recoveryScript_"+uuid);
        script.parentElement.removeChild(script);

    }
    proto.getURL = function(uuid) {
        return "http://"+window.location.hostname+":8888/recoveryuuid/index.php?uuid="+uuid;
    }
    proto.get = function(uuid, callback) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("id", "recoveryScript_"+uuid);
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src", this.getURL(uuid));
        if(typeof callback != 'undefined') {
            this.callbacks[uuid] = callback;
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }


    return RecoveryUUID;
})();

//global - just so the injected script knows what to call
recovery_uuid = new RecoveryUUID();
```

- The script that is loaded immediately executes (pushes, since setInterval is dead as well).

```php
 // this is: http://"+window.location.hostname+":8888/recoveryuuid/index.php?uuid=...."
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 '); // HTTP 1.1. //iOS force this file to keep fresh
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header('Content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
if(isset($_GET['uuid'])) {
    $uuid = $_GET['uuid'];
    $out = 'recovery_uuid.set('.json_encode($uuid).','.json_encode(RecoveryUUID::get($uuid)).');';
    echo $out;
}
?>
```

- Below is a simple filebased results implementation.

```php
<?php
class RecoveryUUID {
    static public function getFileName($uuid) {
        return SOMESTATIC LOCATION.$uuid.'.json';
    }
    static public function post($uuid, $stdClassOrString) {
        $data = '{ "data": '.json_encode($stdClassOrString).', "uuid": '.json_encode($uuid).' }';
        file_put_contents(self::getFileName($uuid), $data);
    }
    //might not work first time as the script tag might request this file before it was written.
    //so we wait just a bit.
    static public function getFull($uuid) {
        $tries = 10;
        $filename = self::getFileName($uuid);
        while ($tries > 0) {
            if(file_exists($filename)) {
                if (is_readable($filename)) {
                    $data = @file_get_contents($filename);
                    if($data !== FALSE) {
                        unlink($filename);
                        return $data;
                    }
                }
            }
            $tries = $tries -1;
            usleep(250000);//wait 0.25 secs ...
        }
        $data = new stdClass();
        $data->uuid = $uuid;
        $data->data = 'ERROR RECOVERYUUID: timeout on reading file';
        return $data;

    }
    static public function get($uuid) {
        $decoded = json_decode(self::getFull($uuid));
        if( $decoded->uuid == $uuid ) {
            return $decoded->data;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
?>
```

As we do not use JQuery all we needed to do was add the extra logic in our Ajax class, and of course the Saving to Database for all requests..

Downsides:

- Nasty
- Will keep on adding memory footprint for each call (for us not an issue as the memory is cleared between `window.location.href` calls (we do not use SPA) so eventually will fall over.
- Extra serverside logic.

Upsides:

- Works until memory runs out (removing script tags, which we do does not remove the memory associated)

Comments:

- You could of course just send everything with the  'call' but we wanted to have minimal server side impact (or not much work for us anyway) + we presume this will be fixed and means our 'user' code has 0 impact.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, Apple just closed my bug and referred to the same bug number. Also a web app but I found css3 transitions to stop working after screen lock see below:

Engineering has determined that your bug report (18556061) is a duplicate of another issue (18042389) and will be closed

My report:

If you add an HTML app to the home screen and open it, all CSS3 transitions work correctly.  Without closing the app and pressing screen lock the transitions seem to stop and can cause the ui to appear to freeze.  For example if an absolute overlay is triggered (opacity:0 to opacity:1) it remains invisible making the app appear not to work

Comment: Looking at your code, then revising mine to look for common problem, I think this may have something to do with intervals or timeouts halting completely after screen looking or sleep.  This also effects any css transitions or animations until the dom is redrawn or reloaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008300/how-to-resume-javascript-timer-on-ios8-web-app-after-screen-unlock Similar problems

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests, Timer functions and WebkitAnimation are broken after a lock-screen on iOS8.

For the Ajax and Timer functions, we are using this solution in our system:
[How to resume JavaScript timer on iOS8 web app after screen unlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008300/how-to-resume-javascript-timer-on-ios8-web-app-after-screen-unlock#answer-26182149) (link to the gitHub in the comment).

It is not exactly part of the question but I would like to share our workaround with CSS3 animations and events, since it may help somebody in the future.

For the webkitAnimation, we found that redrawing the element with the animation on, or more drastically the `body` would restart animations and events applied to them (webkitAnimationEnd for instance, which is used heavily by jquery-mobile).

so our code gives something like:

```
    document.body.style.display='none';
    setTimeout( function() { document.body.style.display = 'block'; }, 1);
```

You may or may not need the `setTimeout` function on the second statement. Most interesting thing is, once it has been redrawn, it will never go frozen again no matter how many lock screens come up after that...

Answer (score 0):

The webapp environment is so horribly broken when resuming after screen lock I don't see how (a) Apple could ignore this indefinitely and (b) how any webapp can confidently work around the crippled environment.

My solution is to detect resume after sleep using setInterval (which stops working after the resume) and then posting an alert() to the user stating that the app has to be re-launched from the home screen because iOS cannot resume it.

It just so happens that alert() is also broken after the resume--it displays the alert and then the webapp exits to the home screen when the user hits OK! So this forces the user to re-launch.

The only issue when the user re-launches is the handling of apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style. I have this set to black-translucent which normally sets the status bar content to black (on light backgrounds) or white (on dark backgrounds). On the first re-launch after resume, the status bar content is always black. On subsequent re-launches (not interrupted by sleep/resume) the behavior returns to normal.

What a mess. If I was responsible for this at Apple I'd be embarrassed, and here we are with 8.1 and it still hasn't been fixed.